# How many indices can a long array support in Java?

Tags: java

I have to use a `long` array with an index range from 0 to 33554432.

It gives an error of:

```
"Exception in thread main java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space".
```

Whereas `short` array does not give this error.  I must use a `long` array and the same indices, what can I do?

Comment: You could try [increasing the Java heap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1566026/2071828) but note that `short` is 16bit and `long` is 64bit, you require _a lot_ more space.

Comment: Out of *Memory* - it's not that an Array *can't* contain so many elements, merely that the JVM can't create/allocate an Array that large on the current system (with the supplied JVM options).

Comment: Do you actually need to store 33 million values in these arrays? Or will most of the cells be empty? Consider using a Map where the key is the numeric index.

Comment: Arrays are stored contiguously in Java are they not? Could this be an error due to the fact that there isn't a long enough congious segment of memory (Eg something like a balanced tree or a hashtable might work)

Comment: If it seems you are the first to have a problem, think about your solution. Is your way the right solution? But you haven't tell us your problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can get a hint by the fact that arrays are accessed using integer literals. Since integer literals only go up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, that's how many indices (and elements) your array can have. [arshajii brings up another hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19189659/how-many-indices-long-array-can-support-in-java/19189767?noredirect=1#comment28393549_19189767).

Your problem just has to do with the fact that your application doesn't have enough memory to create that many `long`s but has enough to create that many `short`s. Remember that when an array is initialized, its elements are also initialized to a default value. For primitive types, that value is `0` or `0.0`. Things to consider (depending on your environment)

```
Long[] array = new Long[33554432]; // allocation would work
long[] array = new long[33554432]; // allocation would fail
```

This is because reference types are initialized to `null` reference and so only the reference takes up space. So you could start adding elements, but it would also eventually fail.

Start your application with more memory.

Comment: +1 You can also get a hint by the fact that the `length` field is an `int`.

Answer (score 5):

The array indexes are int. You  get OOM as your default heap size is too small. Try run java with -Xmx512m command line option ( as your array already require 8*33554432 = 268435456, 268 MB)

Answer (score 2):

Array range should be within maximum value of `int`.

According to JLS

> Arrays must be indexed by int values.
>   An attempt to access an array component with a long index value
>   results in a compile-time error.

Comment: Since when is 2^31-1 < 33554432? He is just running out of memory and needs to adjust the max heap size with `-Xmx`